# How to do keyboard with a buttons in xamarin.android?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rbX2.png) design but I do not know how to program to enter several numbers in the edit text every time a button is pressed. Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> but I do not know how to program to enter several numbers in the edit text every time a button is pressed.

Use `Append` method of the `TextView`, for example, find your `TextView` in activity:

```
TextView tv = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv);
```

Then in the click event of `Button`, append the `Text` of `Button` to this `tv`, here I append a random number each time when button is clicked:

```
Random r = new Random();
tv.Append(r.Next(9).ToString());
```